# What happened to the limit of integration when using Tonelli's Theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, probability-theory, multivariable-calculus

I recently had encounter the integral
$$\int_0^{\infty}{\Bigg[\int_0^x{1}dy\Bigg]f(x)dx}.$$

My question is why is the integral above equal to 
$$\int_0^{\infty}1{\Bigg[\int_y^{\infty}{f(x)}dx\Bigg]dy}?$$

In particular, I am interested on how to get the limit of integration with $[y,\infty]$ for $dy$?

My understanding is that when using Tonelli's Theorem, the integrals are interchangeable. That is, I must have

$$\int_0^{\infty}{\Bigg[\int_0^x{1}dy\Bigg]f(x)dx}=\int_0^x{\Bigg[\int_0^{\infty}{f(x)dx}\Bigg]dy}$$

Can you please help me realize where did I go wrong and how to get the correct limit of integration? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Tonelli's theorem you integrate over the entire space. You have to write the given integral as integral of $f(x)I_{\{(x,y):y<x\}}$ (where $I_A$ is the characteristic function of $A$). Note that $f(x)I_{\{(x,y):y<x\}}=f(x)I_{\{(x,y):x>y\}}$. Also $\int f(x)I_{\{(x,y):x>y\}}dx=\int_y^{\infty} f(x) dx$ for fixed $y$. Similarly, $\int f(x)I_{\{(x,y):x>y\}}dy=\int_0^{x} f(x)dx$ for fixed $x$.

Comment: Thank you Sir @Kavi Rama Murthy for your help. Am I correct if I say that I only need to work on the innermost integral? While the outermost integral is fixed with limit of integration 0 to infinity?

Comment: Yes, in either of the two iterated integrals the outer integral is from $0$ to $\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Apply Tonelli’s theorem to

$$\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty f(x) \chi_{\{y\leqslant x\}}\, dy \, dx$$

where the indicator function takes the value $1$ when $y \leqslant x$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the help @RRL. Is it okay to ask why I need to introduce the characteristic function in the integral? Thanks

Comment: @JrAntalan: Because Tonelli’s and Fubini’s theorem apply to integrals with respect to the product measure over $S \times T$ where $S$ and $T$ are fixed measure spaces.  The interval $[0,x]$ is not fixed as $x$ varies.

Comment: All clear now @RRL thanks for the help.

Comment: @JrAntalan: You're welcome. Happy to help.